# Azure service principal reset

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a k8s cluster running in Azure and I have always reset the service principal credentials by using Azure CLI: `az ad sp credential reset --name <xyz> --years 2`. Afterwards I have updated the AKS cluster with the new service principal credentials, see [update AKS Cluster credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/update-credentials#update-aks-cluster-with-new-service-principal-credentials). After this the cluster will be restarted.

For a production environment I want to avoid restarting the cluster after resetting the credentials, so I was thinking to use the same password as before. So old password=new password. This is achieved using `az ad sp credential reset --name <xyz> --years 2 --password <1234>`

Now my question is: should I update the AKS cluster with new service principal credentials even if I use the same password as before? Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: What would be the reason for resetting the credentials if they'll be the same anyway?  Also: you might benefit from using [managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).

Comment: extending the expiry time

Comment: you should use managed identity as rickvdbosch already said. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#update-an-aks-cluster-to-managed-identities) how to update an AKS cluster to managed identities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's not require to update or restart the AKS cluster with new service principal credentials even if you are using the same password as before.

Since you are using the same password at AKS level and only reseting with same password at service principal level for sake of not to expire password.

Note : If you were resting with different password as you are using currently in that case you have to update and reset the AKS cluster.

For the benifits You can use of [***managed identity***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#update-an-aks-cluster-to-managed-identities) rather than service principle as **rickvdbosch** and **Philip Welz** Suggested in the comment itself.

You can now update an AKS cluster currently working with service principals to work with managed identities by using the following CLI commands.

```
az aks update -g <RGName> -n <AKSName> --enable-managed-identity
```

Comment: in case i change/use a new pw i have to restart the AKS only the user stored in /etc/kubernetes/azure.json.
if i re-use the same password then no restart is needed